# Why does an Action Text attachment render out an "action-text-attachment" tag when rendered as HTML?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, trix, actiontext

I understand that Action Text attachments are store in the DB in a compressed form that appears as an "action-text-attachment" tag. However when rendered using `to_trix_html` this tag is not rendered as I suppose it would mess with Trix's internal model.

I cannot understand why this tag is required when Rich Text is rendered as HTML (for example in a `show` action). I'd really appreciate if someone could explain why this has been designed this way.

Comment: check this https://medium.com/@st0012/disassembling-rails-how-does-actiontext-deal-with-file-upload-3ec92d7a22c6

Comment: I think you could also open an issue about it in github about this

Answer (score 1):

its need to be there as an identifier and its saved like that inside the database

the tag contain 5 attributes `content-type`
`url`
`filename`
`filesize` and `sgid`

`sgid` is Signed Global IDs its unique to each file the function is as an anti-tamper and identifier about the attached file

as for the `.to_trix_html` giving different tag yes its need to be like that

because we want different way to handle the attachment inside the trix editor and when it outside the trix editor.

and if you want to know more about how the attachments works in action_text you could check this blog [post](https://medium.com/@st0012/disassembling-rails-how-does-actiontext-deal-with-file-upload-3ec92d7a22c6)